# Not able to create a admin user in Git Lab server

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab

I have installed gitlab server using docker compose but after the installation I am not getting a default screen where we create first Admin user. Instead of that it is asking me to enter username and password.

Answer (score 0):

If I see this correctly, the gitlab_root_password should be set in the Compose file. This should then be used to log in for the first time.

Source: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html#install-gitlab-using-docker-swarm-mode